# why block and inline element border collapsing?

Tags: html, css

```css
/* css reset*/
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* custom styling */
p {
   border-style: dotted;
}

span {
   border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- title of the website -->
    <title>Learning html and css</title>
    <!-- meta charset -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- stylesheet -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheets-used/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
     <!-- content of the website -->
     <p>Learning html and css</p>  
     <span>Learning html and css</span>
</body>
</html>
```

i m new to html and css. i was playing with border-style and found out that using block and inline element make border collapse. run the code and see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a collapsing. Border applied to inline element doesn't affect the layout:

> The vertical padding, **border** and margin of an inline, non-replaced box start at the **top and bottom of the content area**, and has nothing to do with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when calculating the height of the line box. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)</sup>

You get a collapsing by coincidence. If you increase the border width you will better see what is happening:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  border-style: solid;
}

span {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!-- content of the website -->
<p>Learning html and css</p>
<span>Learning html and css</span>
<span style="border-width:5px;">Learning   css</span>
<span style="border-width:15px;">Learning   css</span>
<span style="border-width:25px;">Learning   css</span>
```

The span element will not move and the border is *overlapping* the content.

If you don't want such behavior, use `inline-block` elements

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


p {
  border-style: solid;
}

span {
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!-- content of the website -->
<p>Learning html and css</p>
<span>Learning html and css</span>
<span style="border-width:5px;">Learning   css</span>
<span style="border-width:15px;">Learning   css</span>
<span style="border-width:25px;">Learning   css</span>
```

Comment: using float work's same as setting inline-block inside span, right?

Comment: @GautamYadav kind of. Not exactly the same since both don't have the same logic but concerning the border, you will have the same output. Only inline level element will not consider border. Float element are block level element